# elasticsearch search for elements with specified ID example

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I want to find certain elements in my elastic search that have a given ID and I can't figure an easy way to do this.

I see http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/ids-query/ but can't for the life of me figure out how to structure a query to use it, or when I do toy around with es-head or curl I see errors like:

```
 Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{"query":{"match_all":{}},"ids
{"values""1","4","100"]}}]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[dailyaggregates][4]: 
query[ConstantScore(NotDeleted(*:*))],from[-1],size[-1]: Parse Failure [No parser for 
element [ids]]]; }]
```

etc. Can anyone tell me how to set this up? Thanks.

edit: My attempt with that error was from es-head but similar errors through curl. I believe what I tried was some variant of this:

```
{
   "query": {
   "match_all": {}
   },
  "ids": {
    "values": [
     "100"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you paste your curl command verbatim?  The example you linked should work, so it's probably a question of where you strayed.  :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Posted what I'm using. I've tried moving it around, like inside the query and get similar errors...hopefully just something dumb.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`ids` is a type of query, just like `match`, or `match_all`.  So the format should be:

```
{"query":{ "ids":{ "values": [ 100 ] } } }
```

You can alternatively do it as a filter, like so:

```
{"filter":{ "query": {"ids":{ "values": [ 100 ] } } } }
```

Comment: Good man. Thanks very much. I find the English difficult to understand in the ES docs, so understand the terms has evaded me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`GET /{YOUR_INDEX_NAME}/_doc/{ID}`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).